# Auto-open chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am new to chrome app development as well as to javascript and now building a chrome app that needs to be automatically open or show a popup at a particular time. I can get the system time and show a popup at that time. But i cant do it when the app is not opened. So is there any way to open a popup automatically in a chrome app even when the app is not opened by the user?

Comment: chrome-app or chrome-extension?

Comment: chrome app. and sorry to say that i cant find the actual difference between two. :(

Comment: @HariKrishnan In extensions you can do it easily, because they run in the background and you can change the DOM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`chrome.alarms` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms) in your [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_lifecycle) to wake up at a specified time and launch the app or show a notification.

```
chrome.alarms.create("some_name", {when: epoch_time});

// This code MUST be on top level of event script
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
  if (alarm.name === "some_name") {
    // Do stuff: show a chrome.notification, chrome.app.window.create, etc.
  }
});
```

Comment: is there any format for how to write the epoch_time?

Comment: You can use `Date.now()` to get current time in milliseconds. Just add what you need, e.g. `Date.now() + 1000*60*60*24*5` for 5 days in the future. There are examples in the docs.